# Ruby: Why do I get warning "regex literal in condition" here?

Tags: ruby

A simple Ruby program, which works well (using Ruby 2.0.0):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
while gets
    print if /foo/../bar/
end
```

However, Ruby also outputs the warning *warning: regex literal in condition*. It seems that Ruby considers my flip-flop-expression /foo/../bar/ as dangerous.

My question: Where lies the danger in this program? And: Can I turn off this warning (ideally only for this statement, keeping other warnings active)?

BTW, I found on the net several discussions of this kind of code, also mentioning the warning, but never found a good explanation why we get warned.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the warning by using an explicit match:

```
while gets
  print if ~/foo/..~/bar/
end
```

[`Regexp#~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html#method-i-7E) matches against `$_`.

I don't know *why* the warning is shown (to be honest, I wasn't even aware that Ruby matches regexp literals against `$_` implicitly), but according to the [parser's source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/parse.y#L9638), it is shown unless you provide the `-e` option when invoking Ruby, i.e. passing the script as an argument:

```
$ ruby -e "while gets; print if /foo/../bar/ end"
```

I would avoid using `$_` as an implicit parameter and instead use something like:

```
while line = gets
  print line if line=~/foo/..line=~/bar/
end
```

Comment: OP's code works OK - there are warnings, but otherwise behaviour is identical - it looks to me that it is just the Ruby parser warning system cannot see the implied match (and truthy return value). In fact I'd consider this a bug in Ruby parser, albeit an obscure and relatively harmless one.

Comment: @NeilSlater interesting, I have no idea why the OP's code works.

Comment: It is Ruby showing its Perl roots. The global var `$_` is involved.

Comment: @NeilSlater regarding `print`, yes. But why is a regexp-flip-flop compared against `$_`?

Comment: `gets; :bar if /foo/` has similar behaviour. As does `gets; /foo/ ? 'foo' : 'bar'` . . . but not `gets; /foo/`

Comment: @NeilSlater is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think Neil Slater is right: It looks like a bug in a parser. If I change the code to

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
while gets
  print if $_=~/foo/..$_=~/bar/
end
```

the warning disappears.

I'll file a bug report.